# Flutter error A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I'm using [Fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro) package to handle my project navigations however after reload one of my pages I get this error :

[image]

```
Another exception was thrown: A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list.
```

and here is my Material App code snippet:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  _MyAppState() {
    final router = FluroRouter.appRouter;
    AppRouter.setupRouter(router);
    AppRouter.router = router;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Auth(),
        ),
        ListenableProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
          update: (_, authObj, prevOrders) =>
              Orders(authObj.usrName, authObj.objId)
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
                  initialRoute: root,
                  onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.router.generator,
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  home: authData.isAuth
                      ? TabsScreen()
                      : FutureBuilder(
                          initialData: authData.tryLogin(),
                          future: authData.tryLogin(),
                          builder: (_, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.waiting
                              ? SplashScreen()
                              : AuthScreen()),

                );
```

Comment: Hi! have you find solution to this?

Comment: @DilshodSh unfortunately  no , however I've changed my package. currently I'm using  [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) . it has clear documentation and it's easy to implement